# weird bug with xfce4: menu panel font very small

Tags: debian, xfce, fonts, menu, panel

I am using debian wheezy with xfce4. With some applications I am experiencing a weird phenomena: The menu panel sometimes has a very tiny font (see Picture). This doesn't happen every time and only with some applications. I noticed it with `git gui` and `ocular`. Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

[image: Note the tiny font of the menu compared with the window title (arrows)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution on my own - maybe it will be useful for somebody: I played around with the "Appearance" in the "Settings" menu. In the "fonts" tab there is a "Use custom DPI value" checkbox. Checking this sets the fontsize to the preferred value.
(I hope I translated the menu options correctly from my german menu)

Comment: I use xfce 4.12. debian 11 and have similar problem (nomachine 7). The texts are tiny. Sound weird but install deb with su instead of sudo fix this.