# Tiny unreadable text on everything after install of Debian 9 to mini pc

Tags: linux, debian, xfce, gui

I have a special pc, a thin client that had a small hard drive! It is a HP-G56N. I love mini pcs. It successfully installed, but upon boot the text is infinitesamally small and unreadable. Looks like little ant tracks. :) why are the default settings like this? Maybe a pc hiccup or had a bad install image, or maybe the hardware being niche caused it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer i found to help someone else on the Internet with a similar issue.

I found [weird bug with xfce4: menu panel font very small](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126281/weird-bug-with-xfce4-menu-panel-font-very-small#126353) which mentioned a custom dpi value. I didn't realize right off that this was related to font size but i unchecked the "use custom DPI setting" checkbox which was checked by default for some reason and text all went back to normal and i sized my text for my 32" tv monitor.

I bet this problem was related to the resolution of a tv as a monitor so use custom dpi was auto calculated based on the tv possibly?

Comment: Note! I also had xfce4 desktop and tools installed and i found this option in an xfce tool